# How does Z3 deal with forall proposition with uninterpreted functions in it?

Tags: z3, forall

Suppose we have two uninterpreted functions func1 and func2:

```
stuct_sort func1(struct_sort);
stuct_sort func2(struct_sort ,int).
```

And they have the relationship:

```
func2(p,n)=func1(p)  if n==1
func2(p,n)=func1(func2(p,n-1))  if n>1
```

What I want to know is that if the following proposition :

```
((forall i:[1,m].func2(p,i)==Z)&&(q==func1(p))) implies (forall i:[1,m-1].func2(q,i)==Z)
```

can be proved to be true in Z3?
In my program, the prove result is `Z3_L_UNDEF`.

When I assign m with a value such as 3, the proposition now is

```
((forall i:[1,3].func2(p,i)==Z)&&(q==func1(p))) implies (forall i:[1,3-1].func2(q,i)==Z);
```

the result is `Z3_L_UNDEF`.
But when I rewrite the case separately(not using forall) as follows, the result is `true`.

```
(func2(p,1)==Z)&&(func2(p,2)==Z)&&(func2(p,3)==Z)&&(q==func1(p)) implies (func2(q,1))&&(func2(q,2)).
```

I can't find out the reason and looking forward to your answer

Answer (score 1):

I encoded your problem using the Z3 Python interface, and Z3 solved it. It found a counterexample for the conjecture.
Of course, I may have made a mistake when I encoded the problem. The Python code is in the end of the post. We can try it online at [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/LSyW). BTW, which version of Z3 are you using? I'm assuming you are using the C API. If that is the case, could you provide the C code you used to create the Z3 formulas? Another possibility is to create a log that records the interaction of your application and Z3. To create a log file, we have to execute `Z3_open_log("z3.log");` before you execute any other Z3 API. We can use the log file to replay all the interaction between your application and Z3.

```py
from z3 import *
# Declare stuct_sort 
S = DeclareSort('stuct_sort')
I = IntSort()
# Declare functions func1 and func2
func1 = Function('func1', S, S)
func2 = Function('func2', S, I, S)

# More declarations
p = Const('p', S)
n = Int('n')
m = Int('m')
i = Int('i')
q = Const('q', S)
Z = Const('Z', S)

# Encoding of the relations 
#    func2(p,n)=func1(p)  if n==1
#    func2(p,n)=func1(func2(p,n-1))  if n>1
Relations = And(func2(p, 1) == func1(p), 
                ForAll([n], Implies(n > 1, func2(p, n) == func1(func2(p, n - 1)))))

# Increase the maximum line width for the Z3 Python formula pretty printer
set_option(max_width=120)
print Relations

# Encoding of the conjecture
# ((forall i:[1,m].func2(p,i)==Z)&&(q==func1(p))) implies (forall i:[1,m-1].func2(q,i)==Z)
Conjecture = Implies(And(q == func1(p), ForAll([i], Implies(And(1 <= i, i <= m), func2(p, i) == Z))),
                     ForAll([i], Implies(And(1 <= i, i <= m - 1), func2(q, i) == Z)))
print Conjecture

prove(Implies(Relations, Conjecture))
```

Comment: I've tested again with latest Z3 using C api with the following input and still undefined : `(implies (and (= (func2 pp 1) (func1 pp))
              (forall (ii Int)
                (implies (> ii 1)
                         (= (func2 pp ii) (func1 (func2 pp (+ ii (* -1 1))))))))
         (implies (and (= q (func1 p))
                       (forall (i Int)
                         (implies (and (>= i 1) (<= i m)) (= (func2 p i) Z))))
                  (forall (i Int)
                    (implies (and (>= i 1) (<= i (+ m (* -1 1))))
                             (= (func2 q i) Z)))))`

Comment: code can be found here: [https://gist.github.com/4491662](https://gist.github.com/4491662)

Comment: Your code uses deprecated functions such as `Z3_check_and_get_model`. BTW, the C++ API is much easier to use. The file `examples/c++/example.cpp` contains many examples using the C++ and the new solver API. Here is a link to this file: http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89c1785b7322#examples/c++/example.cpp

Comment: The C++ API is really easy to use and I have solved the problem using it.Thank you very much for your patience and advises.